# Video cards and PCI-e slots

Tags: graphics-card

Do all PCI-e video cards require a PCI-ex16 slot to work? If not, what video cards don't require a full speed x16 slot?

Note: I'm referring only to new video cards, I am not talking about old AGP or even older PCI cards, only cards that use the PCI-e standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any PCIe device can run down to just a x1 connection as long as it is the first x1 lane, PETp/n0 and PERp/n0 (this is called "Down-plugging"). The problem you're going to run into is the x16 card won't fit into the slot unless it is a x16 slot. If you're comfortable with modifying your motherboard you can cut out the end of the PCIe slot so that the card fits in (but [don't cut the card itself](http://www.overclockers.com.au/article.php?id=395983)) or get a [x1 (or x4/x8) to x16 adapter board](http://www.orbitmicro.com/global/pexp16-sx-16-1-p-1648.html) (which won't fit inside a chassis). There is also potential clearance issues with the card on the end that sticks out off the shorter slot. Also, a lesser concern is a high power card (75W) plugged into a 25W slot.

[image]

Below is an open ended x4 PCIe slot (in the middle closest to the "ASRock" logo). Notice that there are no electrolytic capacitor cans in the way if a x16 card were to be plugged in.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! I guess ill then run a low powered graphics card (prob some gforce 9400) as my primary display on x8 pci-e slot while i use the full speed x16 slot for some other much more powerful card for dedicated CUDA.

Comment: That'll work. Just make sure it fits before buying the card if you can.